# Started Playing with node.js. I have a question

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I just created a HTTP server using this code fro the documentation:

```
var sys = require("sys"),
    http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello World!");
    sys.puts('Connection');
}).listen(8080);

sys.puts("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");**
```

My question is, why when I go to localhost:8080 I got "connection" printed twice? is this a bug?

Comment: It seems so, although on subsequent requests it prints correctly. Something with the first access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser may be requesting the URL twice, once with a HEAD request and once with a GET request. Try using a simple interface, like `telnet`:

```
$ telnet localhost 8080
GET / HTTP/1.0

^]q
```

Leave a blank line after `GET`, and press <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get out.

Comment: Don't think it's a HEAD and GET. Most likely the second requests is in search of the favicon, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: @Ivo: Good call, that's probably it indeed.

Comment: that's correct, I just did: sys.puts(request.url); and the second one if for the favicon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

two requests are sent to the server. The first request is automatically made by the browser, which requests favicon.ico, and of course, the second request is for the URL (localhost:8080).